# windows 10 no image previews creator update

Tags: windows-10

I have just recently updated to Windows 10's "creator update" and so far so good - the only thing I've noticed that I can't see any png  / jpg or image related thumbs in my default "detail" view.

[image]

Tried to clean thumbnail cache and re-assign all images to be opened with the built in "photos" viewer but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: try checking "folder options -> view -> advanced settings" . if "Always show icons, never thumbnails" is checked, uncheck it.

Comment: Open This PC, click File > Change folder and search options. Click the View tab and make sure that the "Display file icon on thumbnails" box is not checked.